# Java reflection in Android: interfaces

Tags: java, android, class, reflection, interface

I've tried some things described in tutorial [here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/java-reflection/): investigating a class's methods. But when I tried to investigate the methods of `android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor`, I've got a `ClassNotFoundException`, cause `Editor` is actually an interface, not a class. So, how can I access methods of an interface using Java reflection? Thanks in advance.

Here is code:

```
    String sClassName = "android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor";  
try {  
    Class classToInvestigate = Class.forName(sClassName);   

    // Dynamically do stuff with this class  
    // List constructors, fields, methods, etc.  

} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {  
    // Class not found!  
} catch (Exception e) {  
    // Unknown exception  
}
```

Comment: show us the code you are trying to use?

Comment: Can you try `Class classToInvestigate = Editor.class;`? Maybe not referencing the class directly makes it unavailable to your project. I don't know how Android compiled code packaging works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to explore an interface in the same way as you would explore a class using reflection. The only difference beeing the fact that `isInterface` will return `true`.

Could you post some code and please precise if you are using JDK or Android SDK in your program as *this* could explain why you get a `ClassNotFoundException`.

Regards, 
 Stéphane

Comment: And do you run this using android sdk or java sdk ? It shall be found using android and won't be found using java sdk as this class is part of android.

Answer (score 0):

Try following class name,

android.app.ContextImpl$SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl